# Create new workspace using Power BI API

Tags: c#, powerbi

I'm trying to automate some processes in my company. **I'm looking for a way to create a new workspace for specific user in my organization.**

*I found API that allows to do that for current logged user - https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups. But I need to create workspace for specific users.*

Is it possible? If so then - how I can achieve that?